# Kivy Popup or Eventloop Interaction?

Tags: python, event-handling, popup, kivy

The first screen of my app has a small menu (in a gridlayout) of three buttons. Two are supposed to open popups. One for Help and one for About. 
The third one changes to another screen.

Only one popup works.  The first one called (in the kivy file) works, the second doesn't open the popup.  If I switch the order in cdd.kv, then the other one works.

Excerpt from cdd.kv:

```
        CDDMainMenuLayout:

            HelpButton:
                size_hint: .5,.5

            MetadataButton:
                size_hint: .5,.5
                on_release: app.root.current = 'metadata'

            AboutButton:
                size_hint: .5,.5
```

Excerpt from main.py:

```
class CDDMainMenuLayout(GridLayout):
    """
    Provides the layout for the three buttons on the home screen.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CDDMainMenuLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.rows = 1
        self.cols = 3
        self.size_hint = (.5,.5)
```

...

```
class CDDButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CDDButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = _('Button')
        self.background_color = colors.grey2

class AboutButton(CDDButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AboutButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = _("About the CDD")
        self.background_color = colors.red1
        a = Popup()
        a.title = _("About Constraint Definition Designer, Version - " + __version__)
        a.content = RstDocument(source='about.rst')
        a.size_hint_x = .8
        a.size_hint_y = .8
        self.bind(on_release=a.open)

class HelpButton(CDDButton):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HelpButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = _("Help")
        self.background_color = colors.green1
        h = Popup()
        h.title = _("CDD Help")
        h.content = RstDocument(source='help.rst')
        h.size_hint_x = .8
        h.size_hint_y = .8
        self.bind(on_release=h.open)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does anything change if you add extra lines `self.popup = h` and `self.popup = a`? One possibility is that your popups are simply being garbage collected since you don't store any references to them. I'm not sure if/how this would give your particular behaviour, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought that by adding them to the kivy language file, then kivy was placing a reference to the instance in the object tree.  Am I wrong about how this works?

Comment: Yes, adding the reference to the popup in the button does fix the problem.  Now that you pointed this out I see where I was confused.  Thanks.

Comment: Widgets in the widget tree do reference one another, but your popups were dynamically constructed with no reference stored to them.